# Explicitly set column value as null based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query which will display 3 column like ID, type and ReceTime.  Below query is displaying ReceTime column value even if type !=1

I want to modify it in a way if type value is one then only give me ReceTime value as per query else put null value in that. ReceTime values are coming from time column in my logger table.

pls help

```
SELECT ID,
 type,
(SELECT (
CASE
  WHEN c.type=1
  AND c.ID   = a.ID
  THEN c.time
    --else null
END )
FROM logger c
WHERE c.type=1
AND c.ID    = a.ID
) AS ReceTime
FROM logger a;
```

Comment: Please show some sample data and the results you want.  The query that you have would seem to be doing what you want, as I understand the problem statement.

Answer (score 4):

I thinks following code will work for you,

```
Select ID,
     type, 
        CASE  WHEN a.type=1   THEN a.time ELSE NULL END as ReceTime
    from 
    logger a;
```

I didn't understand need of `logger`  table twice.

Comment: @kumarb, if my ans is correct you can mark it as Useful

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why you have used the subquery for ctype:

```
SELECT ID,
 type,
CASE
 WHEN type=1
  THEN time
    else null
END as ReceTime
FROM logger
```